# Combining HeadScript javascript with widmogrod/zf2-assetic-module and js in multiple modules

Tags: php, zend-framework2, assetic

Running into a bit of a hurdle, and I can't find any supporting documentation.  My use case is fairly simple.  The `Application` module has javascript that should go into the head, and one of my other modules, `Foo` also has script that should go into the head.  I assumed that this Assetic module could solve that.  Here's what I inferred:

**Application Config**

```
/**
 * Assetic
 */
'assetic_configuration' => array(

    'buildOnRequest'    => true,
    'cacheEnabled'      => false,
    'webPath'           => realpath('public/assets'),
    'basePath'          => 'assets',


     'default' => array(

        'assets' => array(
            '@base_css',
            '@head_js',
        ),

        'options' => array(
            'mixin' => true,
        ),
    ),

     'modules' => array(

        'application' => array(

            # module root path for yout css and js files
            'root_path' => __DIR__ . '/../assets',

            # collection of assets
            'collections' => array(

                'base_css' => array(
                    'assets' => array(
                        'css/*.css',
                    ),
                    'filters' => array(),
                    'options' => array(),
                ),

                'head_js' => array(
                    'assets' => array(
                        'js/*.js',
                    ),
                    'filters' => array(),
                ),

                'base_images' => array(
                    'assets'=> array(
                        'images/*.png',
                    ),
                    'options' => array(
                        'move_raw' => true,
                    )
                ),
            ),
        ),
    ),
),
```

and then in my Foo module...

**Foo Module config**

```
/**
 * Assetic
 */
'assetic_configuration' => array(

     'default' => array(
        'assets' => array(
            '@base_css',
            '@head_js',
        ),

        'options' => array(
            'mixin' => true,
        ),
    ),


    'modules' => array(

        'foo' => array(

            # module root path for yout css and js files
            'root_path' => __DIR__ . '/../assets',

            # collection of assets
            'collections' => array(

                'base_css' => array(
                    'assets' => array(
                        'css/*.css'
                    ),
                    'filters' => array(),
                    'options' => array(),
                ),

                'head_js' => array(
                    'assets' => array(
                        'js/*.js' // relative to 'root_path'
                    ),
                    'filters' => array(),
                    'options' => array(),
                ),

                'base_images' => array(
                    'assets'=> array(
                        'images/*.png'
                    ),
                    'options' => array(
                        'move_raw' => true,
                    )
                ),
            ),
        ),
    ),
),
```

With this config, unfortunately, only the Foo module's javascript makes its way into head_js.js.  I'm feeling like that meme with Milton in it, going "I was told there would be asset combining!" :)

Any help you could offer, is appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: As note, if I trash modules->foo->head_js, then the head_js in applications *does* make its way in.

Comment: So one of the things that happens with module configuration files is that they all get merged together and some keys (specially ones not associated with one of the DiCs) are overridden. Which allows you to override default configurations. It's possible that, that is what is happening here, also since 'application' & 'foo' are different keys, I don't see why they would override each other. Try doing a dump of the config from a controller, `$this->getServiceLocator()->get('Config')`, and see if all of the keys are appearing as they should (merged) for Assetic's config.

Comment: Hey, thanks for taking a stab at it Adrian.  Doesn't seem to be a config issue.  I was trying to avoid cracking open the source to try to understand it.

Comment: Then the issue is probably on how the Assetic module handles the config keys. What your comment suggests is that (assuming you're loading Module Foo after Module Application) the config for Foo is somehow overriding or taking precedence over the Application config. So, if it's not in how the configs are being merged, then it's probably on how the Assetic reads the config array. Good luck!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ok - I've figured it out.  Hopefully this helps someone else one day.  The configuration keys I noted above weren't inaccurate -- but -- they weren't crafted properly when a secret undocumented feature is considered; had to crack the source open to learn that **including the word 'head' in an asset bundle actually autoloads it in the head**.  It's a nice feature in the end, but really a head scratcher when you're not aware of it.

Comment: Thank you! I was trying to load a script in the head section but I couldn't find anywhere how to use it, I was about to crack the code as well but I gave stack overflow a shot and I'm glad I did.